# Properly set-up indepenent variables for polynomial logistic regression

Tags: logistic, polynomial, variable

I would like to conduct an analysis to identify factors that affect whether or not a first purchase was made.

In this context, there are three outcomes I want to predict:

1. Did not buy anything
2. Did buy something within first week
3. Did buy something between first week and first month

The question I have arises from how to prepare some of the independent variables, in particular having received a particular marketing email.

In this context, would it be correct (in light of the outcomes we want to predict) to label the marketing e-mail variable as such:

1. Has received a marketing e-mail before the first purchase (this includes all those, who have received a marketing e-mail but either did not buy something, bought something within the first week or bought something within the first month)
2. Has not received a marketing e-mail before the first purchase (this again includes all those who have not received a marketing e-mail but either did not buy something, bought something within the first week or bought something within the first month)

or do I need to somehow differentiate this independent variable further given that it will be a mix of those who have made a purchase and those who have not made a purchase?

Any input and suggestion is much appreciated!